# ClassCastException : android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

I am trying to implement ShareActionProvider but getting :

```
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145): Process: com.learn2crack.tab, PID: 1145
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider cannot be cast to android.view.ActionProvider
```

**menu.xml:**

```
  <item
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:title="@string/share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
```

**I imported this to my class:**

```
    import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
```

**complete Log:**

```
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145): Process: com.learn2crack.tab, PID: 1145
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider cannot be cast to android.view.ActionProvider
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.readItem(MenuInflater.java:374)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:160)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:110)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.learn2crack.tab.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:72)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:436)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-20 04:14:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the entire logcat exception and the class where the menu is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
     <item
      android:id="@+id/share"
      android:title="@string/share"
      yourapp:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
      yourapp:showAsAction="always" />
    ...
</menu>
```

Check the topic **Using the ShareActionProvider**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: bro what do you mean by : yourapp

Comment: i found code there.. but don't know what to write in place of yourapp

Comment: @AbrahimNeil what is line 78

Comment: Line 78:- mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultIntent());

Comment: @AbrahimNeil `mShareActionProvider` is null not initialized properly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47928/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-abrahim-neil)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.[Git Hub link](https://github.com/mohit008/ActionBar/blob/master/src/com/action_bar/MainActivity.java)

add this your java class :

```
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
......
private ShareActionProvider m_provider;
......
{
  m_provider = (ShareActionProvider)menu_item.getActionProvider();
}
```

add this to your `menu.xml`:

```
android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just met this problem today when following [Adding an Easy Share Action](http://developer.android.youdaxue.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html)
on *Android Developer Guide*.

And it turns out that, on the platform earier than Android 4.0, the SharedActionProvider needs to be used with the v7 compat support library **android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider**, which means that you need to:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
```

in your Activity java file.

But in fact after Android 4.0, ShareActionProvider **android.widget.ShareActionProvider** could be used. Therefore the import should be:

```
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
```

Your problem is that: in **menu.xml** you used android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider, but in activity java file you imported android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider. Therefore just changing them to the same one would solve the problem, either android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider (if your minSDK < 14) or android.widget.ShareActionProvider (if your minSDK >= 14) would be okay.